# Guardar valores JSON obtenidos de Google Directions

Tags: android, json

Necesito obtener los datos de un *JSON* obtenido mediante la *API* de *Google Directions*.

Tengo esto de código, que al parecer está correcto:

```
List<Route> routes = new ArrayList<Route>();
JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(data);
JSONArray jsonRoutes = jsonData.getJSONArray("routes");
for (int i = 0; i < jsonRoutes.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonRoute = jsonRoutes.getJSONObject(i);
    Route route = new Route();

    JSONObject overview_polylineJson = jsonRoute.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
    JSONArray jsonLegs = jsonRoute.getJSONArray("legs");
    JSONObject jsonLeg = jsonLegs.getJSONObject(0);
    JSONObject jsonDistance = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("distance");
    JSONObject jsonDuration = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("duration");
    JSONObject jsonEndLocation = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("end_location");
    JSONObject jsonStartLocation = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("start_location");
    JSONArray 

    jsonInstruction=jsonLeg.getJSONArray("html_instructions");
}
```

¿Cómo puedo guardar los valores? Colocaré un *JSON* de ejemplo para que puedan guiarme:

```
{
   "geocoded_waypoints" : [
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "ChIJNZzlDPLWYpYRCJBxIkFwiD0",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      },
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "ChIJheKsagfQYpYRI6X_s8MFSO4",
         "types" : [ "route" ]
      }
   ],
   "routes" : [
      {
         "bounds" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : -33.4907394,
               "lng" : -70.5542248
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : -33.592532,
               "lng" : -70.6199773
            }
         },
         "copyrights" : "Datos del mapa ©2017 Google",
         "legs" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "13.9 km",
                  "value" : 13892
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "31 min",
                  "value" : 1842
               },
               "end_address" : "Alcalde Pedro Alarcón, San Joaquín, Región Metropolitana, Chile",
               "end_location" : {
                  "lat" : -33.4907394,
                  "lng" : -70.6199773
               },
               "start_address" : "Auriga 2044, Puente Alto, Región Metropolitana, Chile",
               "start_location" : {
                  "lat" : -33.592532,
                  "lng" : -70.5548994
               },
               "steps" : [
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "80 m",
                        "value" : 80
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 9
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : -33.5919623,
                        "lng" : -70.5543792
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Dirígete al \u003cb\u003enordeste\u003c/b\u003e por \u003cb\u003eAuriga\u003c/b\u003e hacia \u003cb\u003eAries\u003c/b\u003e.\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003eCalle de uso restringido\u003c/div\u003e",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "h``lEbgsmLqBgB"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : -33.592532,
                        "lng" : -70.5548994
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "11 m",
                        "value" : 11
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 10
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : -33.5918992,
                        "lng" : -70.5544702
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Gira a la \u003cb\u003eizquierda\u003c/b\u003e con dirección a \u003cb\u003eAries\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "v|_lEzcsmLKP"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : -33.5919623,
                        "lng" : -70.5543792
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "39 m",
                        "value" : 39
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 14
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : -33.5916156,
                        "lng" : -70.5542248
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Gira a la \u003cb\u003ederecha\u003c/b\u003e con dirección a \u003cb\u003eCentral\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "j|_lEldsmLw@q@"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : -33.5918992,
                        "lng" : -70.5544702
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0.3 km",
                        "value" : 344
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 51
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : -33.589296,
                        "lng" : -70.5565952
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Gira a la \u003cb\u003eizquierda\u003c/b\u003e con dirección a \u003cb\u003eAv. Troncal San Francisco\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "rz_lEzbsmLIL}@|AGLKLQTKLYVUPy@d@iAl@k@Xg@t@mA`B"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : -33.5916156,
                        "lng" : -70.5542248
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "47 m",
                        "value" : 47
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 11
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : -33.5888809,
                        "lng" : -70.5566925
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Continúa recto",
                     "maneuver" : "straight",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "bl_lEvqsmLsAP"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : -33.589296,
                        "lng" : -70.5565952
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "2.2 km",
                        "value" : 2236
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "6 min",
                        "value" : 330
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : -33.5768974,
                        "lng" : -70.5755764
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Gira a la \u003cb\u003eizquierda\u003c/b\u003e con dirección a \u003cb\u003eAv. Troncal San Francisco\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "ni_lEhrsmL]r@[z@GZCHCFELINEHGFSRYTe@`@KJYZSXWf@MZGNGNGTGPCLCLU`B[`Co@rFGd@EPELMXYn@eBfCU\\UXSXcAzA{AtBaApAEFqAvAGDm@n@GFYZu@r@k@f@u@r@UXuAjCKR}@bBaBbDmCdFg@dAQ`@Yx@ITWz@Sb@q@dAm@x@k@v@k@x@g@p@q@bAILGHeCtDuBtCe@p@s@nA"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : -33.5888809,
                        "lng" : -70.5566925
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0.8 km",
                        "value" : 835
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "2 min",
                        "value" : 124
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : -33.5740375,
                        "lng" : -70.5826933
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Gira levemente a la \u003cb\u003eizquierda\u003c/b\u003e con dirección a \u003cb\u003eGabriela Ote\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-slight-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "r~|kEjhwmLUdAOt@O`@K`@EVAJ@L[hB]|AI`@Y|AYxAGZYzAWvAERGRGLGHQHQDQ@K@mABe@@A?O@WBQBKDQHUPQXEJGNAHCHAJAJAX?PHfATfCBZ@BFd@"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : -33.5768974,
                        "lng" : -70.5755764
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0.7 km",
                        "value" : 698
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "2 min",
                        "value" : 101
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : -33.5678508,
                        "lng" : -70.58396239999999
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Gira a la \u003cb\u003ederecha\u003c/b\u003e con dirección a \u003cb\u003eAv. Concha Y Toro\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "vl|kExtxmLgBRkC^m@HWDk@F]D_ALe@DUDYB]DsFn@oALa@FWBqAPKBaEf@"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : -33.5740375,
                        "lng" : -70.5826933
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "5.4 km",
                        "value" : 5433
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "10 min",
                        "value" : 603
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : -33.5209376,
                        "lng" : -70.5990908
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Continúa por \u003cb\u003eAv. Vicuña Mackenna\u003c/b\u003e/\u003cb\u003eAv. Vicuña Mackenna Ote.\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "`f{kEv|xmLmALkBLeD\\o@JwFh@kBHe@DOBaIz@SBw@De@DgBJ}@LM@mBVsANSBg@FmD`@aBPwAJeAHMBy@F_AHUB_BNgEl@oEZQBoBTUDsAJaBRuGp@k@FkBRwFb@mDXuD^WDUHKDa@N]Nq@XoBp@oAb@KBiDhAo@PoCx@KDi@R]LqEfBq@RgBn@sAd@iA^{C~@oXnJ{JhDcFfBuIxCk@Py@RoCv@yAb@cCt@SLmJtCKBOF}Bv@_Ct@mBx@a@NeA^oA^C@oAb@[Hs@Pa@Lk@R[H{@Vo@RWHIBQFKD]Ng@VUJKF"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : -33.5678508,
                        "lng" : -70.58396239999999
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "3.3 km",
                        "value" : 3317
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "7 min",
                        "value" : 401
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : -33.4961257,
                        "lng" : -70.6164586
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Continúa recto por \u003cb\u003eAv. Vicuña Mackenna\u003c/b\u003e/\u003cb\u003eAv. Vicuña Mackenna Ote.\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "straight",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "z`rkEh{{mLs@b@m@\\a@TwE~Ck@`@sBrAk@^iAr@KFqBvA{@j@_BfA_@^SR_@b@i@p@QTcBpBgAxAKLqBlCY`@ORq@|@a@j@o@x@sAbBKLW\\{@bAmDvEMPy@dAq@t@a@l@eArAg@n@[^mA~Ag@r@_BvBaAtA}@fA[`@gDhFi@l@GFWVSLSJm@N{@Lw@L_@FoANsCb@UDeCb@MBI?wC`@iJjAQBQDYBmMxAUDM@cDj@eAPODyBb@yAR"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : -33.5209376,
                        "lng" : -70.5990908
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0.2 km",
                        "value" : 167
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 47
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : -33.4962922,
                        "lng" : -70.6180809
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Gira a la \u003cb\u003eizquierda\u003c/b\u003e con dirección a \u003cb\u003eAv. Salvador Allende\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "xemkEzg_nLK@O@D\\Lp@f@nF"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : -33.4961257,
                        "lng" : -70.6164586
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0.5 km",
                        "value" : 506
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 87
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : -33.4918286,
                        "lng" : -70.61912989999999
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Gira a la \u003cb\u003ederecha\u003c/b\u003e con dirección a \u003cb\u003eSan Juan\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "xfmkE~q_nLe@FkC\\gBVa@FM@mATUBkCb@MByCb@_BTy@L"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : -33.4962922,
                        "lng" : -70.6180809
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "59 m",
                        "value" : 59
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 12
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : -33.491807,
                        "lng" : -70.6197696
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Gira a la \u003cb\u003eizquierda\u003c/b\u003e con dirección a \u003cb\u003eEl Pinar\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "|jlkEpx_nLCvA?f@"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : -33.4918286,
                        "lng" : -70.61912989999999
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0.1 km",
                        "value" : 120
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 42
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : -33.4907394,
                        "lng" : -70.6199773
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Gira a la \u003cb\u003ederecha\u003c/b\u003e con dirección a \u003cb\u003eAlcalde Pedro Alarcón\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003eEl destino está a la derecha.\u003c/div\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "xjlkEp|_nLe@B_BRoAP"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : -33.491807,
                        "lng" : -70.6197696
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  }
               ],
               "traffic_speed_entry" : [],
               "via_waypoint" : []
            }
         ],
         "overview_polyline" : {
            "points" : "h``lEbgsmLqBgBKPw@q@ILeAjB]b@e@d@oAv@uBfAuBvCsAP]r@c@vAWn@MPm@h@q@l@m@t@e@bAO^WbAq@bFw@xGK^g@hAeDxE_DpEgAxAoCtCoAnAaBzAUXuAjCiAvBoFhKy@fBoAnDwDpFkBlC{FjIyA`Ce@zB[bAGb@@L[hBg@~Bs@vD_AbFO`@YRc@FyADoAF]Hg@ZWd@IXETCd@HxAXbDHh@sFr@oC\\uC\\cKjAwH`AyDZuEh@wFh@kBHu@HuI~@}AJgBJ}@L{BX}H|@mGj@oFd@gEl@oEZaCXaNvAwCZeL|@mEd@a@N_A^aDjAuHbC{C~@gA`@cGzB{DtAeF~Akd@xOyP`GeBd@iFzAcCt@SLyJxCmC~@_Ct@mBx@gBn@sA`@kBl@}C|@mCx@]LeAf@cCtAyKjHuBrA}B~A{CrBs@r@_E|E_FvGsCvDsDrE{DhFkBzBgB`CcAnAwG`JyAhBgDhFi@l@_@^g@Xm@N{@LwATcFr@{Ch@yOpBkOfBmGdAiCh@eBTO@D\\Lp@f@nFqDd@iC^}F~@aIjAC~BeCVoAP"
         },
         "summary" : "Av. Vicuña Mackenna/Av. Vicuña Mackenna Ote.",
         "warnings" : [],
         "waypoint_order" : []
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Para dejar todo más claro, debo obtener la distancia de viaje, puntos del viaje, tiempo de viaje e instrucciones del viaje. ¿Cómo hacerlo?

Comment: Te puede interesar en este caso usar Gson

Comment: Mas tarde mirare de computar ese json y poder extraer los datos, te dejo una respuesta que de momento vayas investigando con el uso de gson.

Comment: @zhet he agregado una respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente debes revisar la estructura para que puedas parsear correctamente tu archivo .json, como ejemplo [el archivo](http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/ceyWihxzOq?indent=2) que sugieres en tu pregunta puedes verlo [**aquí**](http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/ceyWihxzOq?indent=2) .

Debes considerar esto

La respuesta .Json puede ser de dos tipos:

> - Si el .json inicia con { se considera como objeto Json.
> - Si el .json inicia con [ es considerado como Arreglo Json

De acuerdo a la estructura del archivo .json, tu parser sería :

```
private void parseJson(String data){
    List<Route> routes = new ArrayList<Route>();
    JSONObject jsonData = null;
    try {
        jsonData = new JSONObject(data);
        JSONArray jsonRoutes = null;

        //Obtiene el JSONArray de routes.
        jsonRoutes = jsonData.getJSONArray("routes");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonRoutes.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonRoute = jsonRoutes.getJSONObject(i);
        Route route = new Route();
        //Obtiene objeto overview_polyline.
        JSONObject overview_polylineJson = jsonRoute.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
        //Obtiene JSONArray legs.
        JSONArray jsonLegs = jsonRoute.getJSONArray("legs");
        //Obtiene los objetos de array legs,
        for (int j = 0; j < jsonLegs.length(); j++) {

            JSONObject jsonLeg = jsonLegs.getJSONObject(j);
            //Obtiene el JSONObject de distance.
            JSONObject jsonDistance = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("distance");
            //Obtiene el JSONArray de traffic_speed_entry.
            JSONArray jsonTrafficSpeedEntry = jsonLeg.getJSONArray("traffic_speed_entry");
            //Obtiene el valor de end_address.
            String jsonEndAddress = jsonLeg.getString("end_address");
            //Obtiene el JSONArray de via_waypoint.
            JSONArray jsonViaWayPoint = jsonLeg.getJSONArray("via_waypoint");
            //Obtiene el valor de start_address.
            String jsonStartAddress = jsonLeg.getString("start_address");
            //Obtiene el JSONObject de start_location.
            JSONObject jsonStartLocation = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("start_location");

            //Obtiene el Array steps.
            JSONArray jsonSteps = jsonLeg.getJSONArray("steps");
            //Obtiene elementos de steps
            for (int k = 0; k < jsonSteps.length(); k++) {
                JSONObject jsonObjectInstruction = jsonSteps.getJSONObject(k);
                //Obtiene el valor de html_instructions
                String jsonInstruction = jsonObjectInstruction.optString("html_instructions");
                Log.i(TAG, "jsonInstruction: " + jsonInstruction);
                JSONObject jsonStepDistance = jsonObjectInstruction.getJSONObject("distance");
                Log.i(TAG, "jsonStepDistance: " + jsonStepDistance);
                String jsonTravelMode = jsonObjectInstruction.optString("travel_mode");
                Log.i(TAG, "jsonTravelMode: " + jsonTravelMode);
                String jsonManeuver = jsonObjectInstruction.optString("maneuver");
                Log.i(TAG, "jsonManeuver: " + jsonManeuver);
                JSONObject jsonStepStartLocation = jsonObjectInstruction.getJSONObject("start_location");
                Log.i(TAG, "jsonStepStartLocation: " + jsonStepStartLocation);
                JSONObject jsonStepPolyline = jsonObjectInstruction.getJSONObject("polyline");
                Log.i(TAG, "jsonStepPolyline: " + jsonStepPolyline);
                JSONObject jsonStepDuration = jsonObjectInstruction.getJSONObject("duration");
                Log.i(TAG, "jsonStepDuration: " + jsonStepDuration);
                JSONObject jsonEndLocation = jsonObjectInstruction.getJSONObject("end_location");
                Log.i(TAG, "jsonEndLocation: " + jsonEndLocation);
            }
            //Obtiene el objeto duration.
            JSONObject jsonDuration = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("duration");
            //Obtiene el objeto end_location.
            JSONObject jsonEndLocation = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("end_location");

            Log.i(TAG, "jsonDistance: "+ jsonDistance );
            Log.i(TAG, "jsonTrafficSpeedEntry: "+ jsonTrafficSpeedEntry );
            Log.i(TAG, "jsonEndAddress: "+ jsonEndAddress );
            Log.i(TAG, "jsonViaWayPoint: "+ jsonViaWayPoint );
            Log.i(TAG, "jsonStartAddress: "+ jsonStartAddress );
            Log.i(TAG, "jsonStartLocation: "+ jsonStartLocation );
            Log.i(TAG, "jsonDuration: " + jsonDuration);
            Log.i(TAG, "jsonEndLocation: " + jsonEndLocation);
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "TERMINA PARSER!");

    }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "parseJson() " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "parseJson() " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Este es un ejemplo mostrando las instrucciones de navegación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes descargar el ejemplo [aquí](https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-parse-JSON), únicamente define tu url o usa esta para simular tu .json online:

http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/ceyWihxzOq?indent=2

Como otra opción puedes usar GSON, revisa este articulo:

[**TRABAJANDO CON JSON EN ANDROID (GSON)**](https://geekytheory.com/trabajando-con-json-en-android-gson)

Comment: gracias, tu respuesta me sirvio

Comment: @zhet excelente! No es complejo parsear un json solo debes saber donde obtener un array, objeto o string! . Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Si tienes el JSON como un String una solución fácil es usar `Gson` para pasar ese JSON a un objeto de tu modelo. Imagina que tengo un json con un coche y quiero crear un objeto Coche con los datos.

```
String jsonCar = "{name: 'Renault', cv: 300, doors_number: 3}";
Gson gson = new Gson();
Car car = gson.fromJSON(json, Car.class)
```

Comment: es solo un ejemplo, ese json es la respuesta de una solicitud al servidor, por ende lo deje como ejemplo

Answer (score 2):

Como comenta el compañero @DavidLuque usando la [librería Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) es muy fácil recorrer por una estructura `json` y extraer los valores

Con la webtool [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) puedes generar los objetos `Gson` a partir de un recurso `json`.

Tutorial de [gson](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/gson-jsonparser.html) para comprender más o menos como se usa.
y para recorrer entre [subestructuras](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-parse-json-to-java/)

...

Answer (score 1):

He estado revisando tu código y parece que esté correcto salvo en la ultima línea:

```
JSONArray jsonInstruction = jsonLeg.getJSONArray("html_instructions");
```

ya que según el **json** que has puesto **html_instructions** se encuentra dentro de cada uno de los objetos de la etiqueta **steps** y no de la etiqueta **legs** que es donde tu estás intentando coger el valor.

Por lo que tendrías que utilizar el siguiente código si quieres coger todos los **html_instructions**:

```
//obtenemos el array de steps
JSONArray jsonSteps = jsonLeg.getJSONArray("steps");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonSteps.length(); i++) {
         //obtenemos cada uno de los steps
         JSONObject jsonStep = jsonSteps .getJSONObject(i);

         //obtenemos los html_instructions
         JSONObject html_instructions = jsonStep .getJSONObject("html_instructions");

         //almacenamos o utilizamos los html_instruction
         ....
    }
```

Por otr parte si tu intención no era la de coger los **html_instructions** y era la de coger los **steps**, te bastaría con utilizar lo siguiente:

```
JSONArray jsonSteps = jsonLeg.getJSONArray("steps");
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda. Saludos.